# How can I fetch (via GET) all JIRA issues? Do I go to the Search node?

Tags: api, jira, etl, data-warehouse

It looks like /api/2/project easily returns all projects in a JIRA instance in JSON format.

I'd like to do the same for issues, but this does not appear to exist.

Is /api/2/search the standard way to do a mass-dump like this? And what is the best way to regularly update this to a database? Would I do something like search (update date > [last entry in database]) and then go through the pagination? Surely I can't be the first person attempting this, though I see no similar guide anywhere online to this (I checked Jira's own docs, no mass-issue-export guide really).

EDIT: Okay it looks like search really is the "issue dump" and not the issue node which, contrary to their documentation, does not default to a collection but really for creating issues or listing one at at time. I'll probably go the route of updated > [whatever last date is in the DB]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have very few issues, you can't fetch all of them at once.
What you can do is to execute the search step by step.

For example, lets say you have 1324 JIRA issues. In order to retrive all of them you have to execute a search similar to this several times:

```
/rest/api/2/search?&maxResults=100&startAt=0
```

This will retrive the first 100 JIRA issues starting from 0.
How to get the others?

When you execute the search, a field named `total` is returned. That field is the number of the total JIRA issues in your system (1324 issues).

The next query will be:

```
/rest/api/2/search?&maxResults=100&startAt=100
```

Repeat this operation, incrementing the value of `startAt` by 100 every time, until all the issues are returned.

Comment: Gotcha --- yeah figured it would be something like that. The startAt=0, I think, would not be very useful for an incremental load of all Jira tickets by last update time. Well, maybe it would -- I guess you can order by update_time asc ... but what happens if a ticket on Page 2 became updated, and is now on Page 1000? Would the 'page logic' dynamically update somehow? Probably best to avoid, and just fetch the 'grab last update time, make it first update time in query now'