# Jira -- How to get issue changelog via REST API - but ALL, not single issue

Tags: api, jira, changelog

I've seen this question many times, but no sufficient answer.

We're trying to dump all JIRA data into our data warehouse/ BI system. Or at least, the interesting parts.

One thing you can do is track status times, cycle time, lead time directly with field durations. This is very easy via JIRA's direct SQL database. The tables changeItem and changeGroup.

Of course the REST JSON API has less performance impact on the database.

However ... there appears to be no equivalent in the rest API of fetching ALL issue change history. Yes, you can fetch the changelog of one issue directly via an API call. If you have 100k issues, are you expected to make 100k API calls, iterating through issue IDs? Sounds like madness.

Is it somehow possible to expand changelogs through the search API, which amasses all issue data? I haven't seen it. Is what I'm seeking here possible? Or will we have to stick to the SQL route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are asking pretty much the same question as before: [How can I fetch (via GET) all JIRA issues? Do I go to the Search node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728461/how-can-i-fetch-via-get-all-jira-issues-do-i-go-to-the-search-node), but additionally interesting in getting changelog data.

Yes, again you have to do it in batch, requesting JIRA API several times.
Here is little bash script, which could help you to do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LDAP_USERNAME='<username>'
LDAP_PASSWORD='<password>'

JIRA_URL='https://jira.example.com/rest/api/2/search?'
JQL_QUERY='project=FOOBAR'

START_AT=0
MAX_RESULTS=50

TOTAL=$(curl --silent -u "${LDAP_USERNAME}:${LDAP_PASSWORD}" -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${JIRA_URL}maxResults=0&jql=${JQL_QUERY}" | jq '.total')
echo "Query would export ${TOTAL} issues."


while [ ${START_AT} -lt ${TOTAL} ]; do
    echo "Exporting from ${START_AT} to $((START_AT + MAX_RESULTS))"
    curl --silent -u "${LDAP_USERNAME}:${LDAP_PASSWORD}" -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${JIRA_URL}maxResults=${MAX_RESULTS}&startAt=${START_AT}&jql=${JQL_QUERY}& expand=changelog" | jq  -c '.issues[]' >> issues.json

    START_AT=$((START_AT + MAX_RESULTS))
done
```

Please note the *expand* parameter, which additionally put all change log to the json dump as well. Alternatively you can use [issue dumper](https://gist.github.com/grundic/cc26b30268fb633d512132dcbf561146) python solution: implement the **callback** to store data to db and you're done.

Comment: Hmm ... I tried expand=changelog on the search API endpoint before I even asked this question -- I didn't notice any additional information/ results. It's certainly not listed on any sort of Jira API documentation as an expand option for this particular endpoint. I didn't think it was possible to bring out the changelog via this endpoint. Perhaps I'll have to double check exactly what logic I used. EDIT: I guess I didn't examine my query results closely enough. The changelog is indeed available on the search endpoint, expand=changelog. Wish this very useful bit of info was better documented

Comment: I have no problem fetching 1000 tickets at a time. It was the '1 ticket' at a time method in their standard documentation that required an issue_id in the URL that seemed very cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Another service worth considering especially if you need to have a feed like list of changes:

```
/plugins/servlet/streams?maxResults=99&issues=activity+IS+issue%3Aupdate&providers=issues
```

This returns a feed of last changes in issues in XML format for some criteria, like users etc. Actually, you may play around with "Activity Stream" gadget on a Dashboard to see hot it works.

[image]

The service has limit of 99 changes at once, but there's paging(see the Show More.. button)